# UK - Spousal Visa Travelling to Mexico for Holiday

Tags: visas, uk, mexico, spouses

I'd like to clarify some information regarding entry to Mexico as tourist. I would greatly appreciate if you could provide assistance to me.

I hold a Philippine Passport, however I have been living in the UK for years now under Spousal Visa/Leave to Remain (Residence and Work Permitted).

On their site and some forums, confirmed if you have "ANY VALID VISA" from countries like UK, you don't need Mexican visa. I just not sure if Spousal or Leave to Remain is included?

Would I still need to acquire a Mexican Visa?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: What possible reason could there be to doubt that "any valid visa" includes a spousal visa or leave to remain?

Answer (score 1):

Even [the Mexican government's own web site](https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) says so.

Translated:

> The foreigner who submits any of the following documents will not require a Mexican visa:
>
> a) Document proving permanent residency in Canada, the United States of America, Japan, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, any of the countries that make up the Schengen Area, as well as in the member countries of the Pacific Alliance (Chile, Colombia and Peru).
>
> b) Valid and unexpired visa from Canada, the United States of America, Japan, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland or any of the countries that make up the Schengen Area.

Comment: I sent an email to Mexican Embassy and I was told to get a visa. What is it really that I have to do? :(

Comment: @TanyaMcAthey Who knows why they said that? It's obviously wrong. Perhaps they didn't read your email correctly? In any event, you do not need a visa for Mexico if you have a valid UK visa or ILR.